# How i can delete one item from product cart

Tags: reactjs, http, frontend, sequelize.js, backend

All other requests work correctly except removeFromBasket.

console: WHERE parameter "id" has invalid "undefined" value.

Backend, deleting function:

```
async removeFromBasket(req, res) {
        const user = req.user
        const {deviceId} = req.body
        const basket = await BasketDevice.destroy({where: {id: deviceId}})
        return res.json(basket)
    }
```

routing file:

```
router.post('/', authMiddleWare,  basketController.addToBasket)
router.get('/', authMiddleWare, basketController.getBasketUser)

router.delete('/', authMiddleWare, basketController.removeFromBasket)
router.delete('/', authMiddleWare, basketController.clearBasket)

module.exports = router
```

Frontend, deleting function:

```
export const removeFromBasket = async (deviceId) => {
    const {data} = await authHost.delete('api/basket', deviceId)
    return data
}
```

[construction of BasketDevice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpKSl.png)

i tried  findOne, findByPk, tried other types of requests(post yes..., put).

Comment: Your server code expects and an object with a device id in it and your front end code sends a raw value. Try `const {data} = await authHost.delete('api/basket', { deviceId })`. Or make the back end not try to destructure it from `req.body` but use `req.body` directly.

Comment: Thx for you answers, but its not working